# What is the correct way to show error response in Retrofit2?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I've created Model class to handle my Retrofit2 Callback:

```
public class ModelSendPhone {

@Expose
@SerializedName("code")
private int code;
@Expose
@SerializedName("user_id")
private int user_id;

public int getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public int getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}
```

And here is my Call code:

```
Call<ModelSendCode> sendCodeCall = getRetrofit().sendCode(params);
sendCodeCall.enqueue(this);
```

Now I noticed that if I enter wrong @Params,the response is giving me error 422 and JSON response body with message something like:

```
{"name":"Unprocessable entity","message":"Wrong params","code":0,"status":422,"type":"yii\\web\\HttpException"}
```

My question is how should I show this "message" in Toast inside onResponse method? My onResponse method not parsing it as I'm implementing `Callback<ModelSendCode>`.

Thanks in-advance

Comment: you can do one thing add all variables in your model and then you can check the status variable and show message

Comment: you mean I have to add something like status variable to check the code of the response by Model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, but I found what I needed. `response.errorBody().string()`
That's the correct way according to [the docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#message--), to get default response on any error, now I will convert it to Json and parse it as I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Your model can be look like this and all will fine just check status in response.

```
public class ModelSendPhone implements Serializable
{
    private String message;

    private String status;

    private String name;

    private int user_id;

    private int code;

    private String type;

    public String getMessage ()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage (String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getStatus ()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus (String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getUser_id ()
    {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id (int user_id)
    {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    public int getCode ()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode (int code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getType ()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType (String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [message = "+message+", status = "+status+", name = "+name+", user_id = "+user_id+", code = "+code+", type = "+type+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: seems legit but, how will my Model class will know that "getCode" is actually response code?

Comment: you must be having different status code for successes and error right

Answer (score 0):

In your onResponse method you'll get a response object of type

```
Response<ModelSendCode>
```

It's an HTTP response. According to the [Square docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#message--)

You can simply do `response.message()` to get the message from the **HTTP** response. You can also check if it's been successful by using `response.isSucessful()`. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have tried this:
if (response.isSuccessful()){
            ModelSendPhone model = response.body();
        }else {
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                Toast.makeText(this, json.optString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Comment: What do you get when you do response.message() ?

Comment: you way is working OK, but my app has multiple-locale